# Writing to EEPROM PIC?

Tags: assembly, pic, eeprom

I'm working on a project in which i need to be able to store a value to the PIC's EEPROM, I have managed to get the read to work but so far i am unable to get the PIC to write to the memory using PIC assembly. This is the code that i have been using , it is derived from the example write code from the data sheet, I am using the 16D630 PIC, and using the PIC assembly language.

```
MOVLW 0x02
MOVWF EEADR
MOVLW 0x01
MOVWF EEDATA
BSF STATUS,RP0 ;BANK 1
BSF EECON1,WREN ;ENABLE WRITE
BCF INTCON,GIE ;DISABLE INTS
MOVLW 0x55 ;UNLOCK WRITE
MOVWF EECON2 ;
MOVLW 0xAA ;
MOVWF EECON2 ;
BSF EECON1,WR ;START THE WRITE
BSF INTCON,GIE ;ENABLE INTS
```

Comment: might want to try the microchip forums if you don't get a response here...  there isn't a lot of specific embedded feedback on here, but sometimes you get lucky

Comment: Thanks Keith, however searching on the forums and PIClists revealed nothing to me :(

Comment: http://www.microchip.com/forums don't forget this one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set appropriate memory bank before your program load **EEADR** and **EEDATA** values.

Use "*Watch*" window to control values in registers **EEADR** and **EEDATA** when you are stepping (F7) over program lines in debbug mode!

```
BSF STATUS,RP0       ;Set BANK 1 first !!!
MOVLW 0x02
MOVWF EEADR
MOVLW 0x01
MOVWF EEDATA

BSF EECON1,WREN ;ENABLE WRITE
BCF INTCON,GIE ;DISABLE INTS
MOVLW 0x55 ;UNLOCK WRITE
MOVWF EECON2 ;
MOVLW 0xAA ;
MOVWF EECON2 ;
BSF EECON1,WR ;START THE WRITE
BSF INTCON,GIE ;ENABLE INTS
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you enable the write WREN flag you should indicate whether you intend to write into program memory (flash) or into eeprom by setting/clearing EEPGD flag in EECON1.